# Delegate for jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery

I got this code today that works for jQuery v7. The problem is that it need to work for 1.3.2 as well. How would I translate it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#dropdown li ul").hide(); 
    $("ul#dropdown").delegate( 'li', 'click', function () {   
    if (!$(this).parent().is("ul#dropdown") ) {
            return false; 
        }  
    $(this).siblings('.' + "current").removeClass("current").children('ul').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).addClass("current").children('ul').slideDown('fast')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option for delegation in `1.3` is [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method

```
$("ul#dropdown li").live('click', function () {   
    if (!$(this).parent().is("ul#dropdown") ) {
            return false; 
        }  
    $(this).siblings('.' + "current").removeClass("current").children('ul').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).addClass("current").children('ul').slideDown('fast')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see is your use of `delegate`, which was added in 1.4. In 1.3.2 your only alternative is to use `live()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#dropdown li ul").hide(); 
    $("ul#dropdown li").live('click', function () {   
        if (!$(this).parent().is("ul#dropdown") ) {
            return false; 
        }  
        $(this).siblings('.' + "current").removeClass("current").children('ul').slideUp('fast');
        $(this).addClass("current").children('ul').slideDown('fast')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to replace `.delegate()` with `.live()` (live is in there since 1.3.0). This would not create the event handler on the `ul node` but on the `document.body`.

That means all events have to bubble further up, but unless you're dealing with tons of event handlers and nodes, there is no noticeable performance difference.

```
$("ul#dropdown li").live('click', function () { 
}
```

Ref.: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)